# Getting result from the `change` dictionary in `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)`

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm writing code to observe the key path `"sortDescriptors"` of a `NSTreeController`. Tried to get the `[NSSortDescriptor]` array from the `change` dictionary, with no luck. I could access `sortDescriptors` property of `object`(cast to `NSTreeController`), but I wonder why I can't do the similar with the `change` dict.

I've read examples [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486951/how-can-i-get-int-values-from-the-change-dictionary-in-kvo-method-observevaluefo). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784886/change-dictionary-in-kvo-always-contains-null-for-selectionindex) indicates it may be a bug. Or does the `change` dictionary only work with "simple" data types? (Array in Swift is value type, and I don't know what term to use here.)

My observing code is like this:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?,
  change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let kind : UInt = change?[.kindKey] as? UInt, 
       let changeKind = NSKeyValueChange(rawValue: kind) {
        guard changeKind == .setting else { return }
        if keyPath! == "sortDescriptors" {
            // the debugger can run into here.
            if let v = change?[.newKey] as? [NSSortDescriptor] {
                print(v) // This never prints. 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is the answered question you linked to not sufficient? There's nothing to add. It's a known limitation/bug of `NSArrayController` and `NSTreeController` that the change dictionary doesn't include the new value.

Comment: Because I thought these are "linked" but not duplicates. But I agree with you now. BTW it seems there still is no apple documentation on this.